# Access pointer to QWidget(Combobox) of the customdelegate

Tags: qt, qwidget, qtableview, qcombobox, qstyleditemdelegate

I have derived a class from `QStyledItemDelegate`. I am using a `QComboBox` in this delegate. This delegate is used in `QTableView`.

My question is, how can i change the index of the Combobox in the delegate programatically i.e how to access the pointer to that widget outside the delegate class ?
 I have checked that `CreateEditor`, `SetEditorData`, `SetModelData` functions (of `QStyledItemDelegate`) are called automatically when we click on the combobox and we cannot call them manually to maniplate the data in the model.

Answer (score 1):

afaik any time you start editing and the combobox is shown, it will allocate a new one. if you want to have a permanent combobox, you should look at

`QTableView::setIndexWidget(const QModelIndex&, QWidget*)`

so you could access the combobox with the following code:

```
const QMoodelIndex idx = model->index(row, column);
QWidget* wid = view->indexWidget(idx);
QComboBox* box = qobject_cast<QComboBox*>(wid);
if (box)
    // do your thing
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have the contents of your combobox as a class member of your delegate in a `QStringList`. Your item delegate can be like :

```
#include <QStyledItemDelegate>

#include <QComboBox>

class ComboBoxDelegate: public QStyledItemDelegate
{
 Q_OBJECT
public:
    ComboBoxDelegate(QObject *parent = 0);

    QWidget *createEditor( QWidget *parent,
                            const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
                            const QModelIndex &index ) const;

    void setEditorData( QWidget *editor,
                            const QModelIndex &index ) const;

    void setModelData( QWidget *editor,
                            QAbstractItemModel *model,
                            const QModelIndex &index ) const;

    void updateEditorGeometry( QWidget *editor,
                            const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
                            const QModelIndex &index ) const;

    QStringList comboItems;

    mutable QComboBox *combo;

private slots:

    void setData(int val);

};

ComboBoxDelegate::ComboBoxDelegate(QObject *parent ):QStyledItemDelegate(parent)
{
}

QWidget *ComboBoxDelegate::createEditor(QWidget *parent, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    combo = new QComboBox( parent );
    QObject::connect(combo,SIGNAL(currentIndexChanged(int)),this,SLOT(setData(int)));
    combo->addItems(comboItems);
    combo->setMaxVisibleItems(comboItems.count());
    return combo;
}

void ComboBoxDelegate::setEditorData(QWidget *editor, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    QString text = index.model()->data( index, Qt::DisplayRole ).toString();

    int comboIndex = comboItems.indexOf(QRegExp(text));

    if(comboIndex>=0)
        (static_cast<QComboBox*>( editor ))->setCurrentIndex(comboIndex);
}

void ComboBoxDelegate::setModelData(QWidget *editor, QAbstractItemModel *model, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    model->setData( index, static_cast<QComboBox*>( editor )->currentText() );
}


void ComboBoxDelegate::updateEditorGeometry(QWidget *editor, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    editor->setGeometry( option.rect );
}

void ComboBoxDelegate::setData(int val)
{
    emit commitData(combo);
    //emit closeEditor(combo);
}
```

When you want to update the items in combobox somewhere in your code just get a pointer to the item delegate by calling `itemDelegateForColumn` and access the `comboItems` member :

```
ComboBoxDelegate * itemDelegate = qobject_cast<ComboBoxDelegate *>(ui->tableView->itemDelegateForColumn(columnIndex));

//Updating combobox items
itemDelegate->comboItems.append("newItem");
...
```

Comment: The problem with this solution is that, Combox of the member variable needs to be set first in order to manipulate the data. which will be set as soon as i click on the combobox in the itemdelegate. So I accessed the model and the standarditem and change the text rather than manipulating the index of the combobox

Comment: I don't get what you mean. Don't you want to modify items in combo box?

Comment: No, i wanted to, but the comboItems will be added to the comboBox, when the `createEditor` is called, which is only called when we interact with the Combobox using the mouse.